# Тег <video> не работает проекте ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, html5, asp.net-mvc

Создал проект MVC5, в нём лежить действие HOME/Index в представлении которого лежит тег `<video>`:

```
<video muted autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="@Url.Action("Index","Video")" /> 
</video>
```

При запуске появлялся чёрный квадрат и всё
(До этого в атрибуте src был указан прямой путь - но это тоже не помогло).
Так же есть действие Video/Index которое возвращает стрим файла:

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Video
    public FileStreamResult Index()
    {
        Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/BG.mp4"), FileMode.Open);

        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "video/mp4");
    }
}
```

Если перейти к действию Video/Index генерируется плеер но видео не запускается. А значит браузер знает что там видео но взять его не может. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попытайтесь добавить в webconfig следующее:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

Добавить нужно в секцию  `<system.webServer>`

Comment: Мимо проходил. А что там за MIME по умолчанию? Он там есть, раз его убирать приходится?

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но до сих пор реакции нет.